# how to call command button click event based on cell value?

Tags: excel, vba, selectionchanged

i have a shipment tracking table with many records, each represent a shipment 
and in a different sheet i have an "Arrival Notification" template , with a command button to update template values and send automatic email to client once their shipment arrives

back to the table,
column "Z" has the shipment arrival date 
column "AH" for the arrival notification .. it can have 2 values only (*SEND*, *SENT*) .. *SEND* for shipments with no notification sent yet , and *SENT* for notifications already sent

WHAT I WANT IS :
for each cell in col "AH" with the value "*SEND*" only, once clicked 
to run the code *CommandButton1_Click* from the second sheet
and then change cell value to "*SENT*"

*what i did was as below , but not working

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Column = Range("AH1").Column Then
Call CommandButton1_Click
Else
Range("AH" & Target.Row).Value = "SENT"
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Use the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event and check the address of the `Target` argument.

Comment: The `Target` argument also has a `.Column` property, btw.

Comment: hey @braX i'm a total beginner btw .. i guess i need explanation for your comments , sorry

Comment: I added an answer that hopefully explains it well enough for you.

Answer (score 0):

First, find the `SelectionChange` event for the `Worksheet` (this is important, as you cannot just place this code anywhere... it has to be in that event.

Then paste this code into it.

```
If Target.Column = 26 Then ' column Z
  CommandButton1_Click
  Range("AH" & Target.Row).Value = "SENT"
End If
```

When you are done, it should look like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Column = 26 Then ' column Z
    CommandButton1_Click
    Range("AH" & Target.Row).Value = "SENT"
  End If
End Sub
```